QGIS "Render Layers as a Group" Ignores Scale-Dependent Visibility
In QGIS 3.40, I've grouped several vector background mapping layers (OS Open Zoomstack data) for easier management. Individual layers (e.g., railway station points) are configured with scale-dependent visibility settings (e.g., display only between 1:1 and 1:40,000), which work perfectly when the layers are rendered independently.
When I enable "Render layers as a group" to manage the group as a single entity (e.g., for simple use in print layouts), these scale settings seem to be ignored, and all layers in the group are rendered regardless of the map scale.
I've tried:

Map themes - I need to dynamically control which layers are displayed in the different maps using project variables, so expressions based on project variables are my preferred approach.
Disabling "Render layers as a group" - whilst this restores scale-dependent behaviour, it means I can't reference the group in the dynamic expressions, making it harder (longer) to include the background mapping in layouts.


Is this behaviour of "Render layers as a group" expected, or is it a potential bug?
Is there a workaround to preserve scale-dependent visibility while rendering layers as a group?
Alternatively, is there another way to reference and manage multiple layers as a single entity for print layouts?


As a workaround, you can set set a data defined override to set a size of 0, or an opacity of 0, when out of the scale range. You would also have to apply this on the labels.
Click the data defined override icon beside the setting of your choice, then edit
For setting a size of 0 or 5:
if (@map_scale  BETWEEN   
    layer_property(@layer ,'max_scale')  AND 
    layer_property(@layer ,'min_scale'), 5, 0)

For the opacity:
if (@map_scale  BETWEEN   
    layer_property(@layer ,'max_scale')  AND 
    layer_property(@layer ,'min_scale'), 100, 0)

The condition (@map_scale BETWEEN layer_property(@layer ,'max_scale')  AND layer_property(@layer ,'min_scale')) should always be the same, just adjust the following values "if condition is true" and "if condition is false"

